# Load iFrame on page callback

Tags: vb.net, iframe, callback, aspxgridview

I'm looking for a way to load a PDF file onto an iFrame whenever a callback is triggered by GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton within an ASPxGridView. The reason for it is that I need a different PDF loaded depending on which row on the ASPxGridView is clicked.

Below is how I (unsuccessfully) handle the callback at the moment:

```
Protected Sub grid_CustomButtonCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs)
    If e.ButtonID = "bnPreview" Then
        Dim grid As ASPxGridView = CType(sender, ASPxGridView)
        Dim key As Object = grid.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, grid.KeyFieldName)
        Dim sFile = UploadReportHelper.GetReport(key)
        If sFile <> "" Then
            frame_preview.Attributes("src") = sFile
        End If 
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page must have something else going on that's preventing it from updating the iframe.  If you isolate it into another project it works.  I just created a new project and tested it. Below works.

**HTML:**

```html
<iframe id="myFrame" runat="server"
        src="http://dell.com" width="100%" height="600">

    Your browser doesn't support iframes

</iframe>

<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" 
            Text="Change IFRAME Source" />
```

**CodeBehind:**

```vb
Protected Sub myButton_Click(sender As Object, 
                             e As System.EventArgs) Handles myButton.Click

    myFrame.Attributes("src") = "http://microsoft.com"

End Sub
```

---

## Edit per comments stating OP is using UpdatePanel

In this case, you simply set the `UpdateMode` on your `UpdatePanel` to `Conditional` and then in your CodeBehind, you call the `.Update()` method of the `UpdatePanel` like below.

**HTML:**

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    
<p>
    <strong>Today's Date:</strong> <%=Now.ToString()%>
</p>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <iframe id="myFrame" runat="server" 
                src="http://dell.com" width="100%" height="600">
        
            Your browser doesn't support iframes

        </iframe>
            
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" 
                        Text="Change IFRAME Source" />
        </p>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```vb
Protected Sub myButton_Click(sender As Object,
                             e As System.EventArgs) Handles myButton.Click

    myFrame.Attributes("src") = "http://microsoft.com"
    myUpdatePanel.Update()

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you're confusing `callback` with `postback`. GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton doesn't cause postback on click, like aspButton would.

Comment: It's still a partial postback if its done asynchronously or are you saying you never go back to the server? There has to be a way to update the client from the server if you are causing a partial postback. What method are you using? `UpdatePanel`s?

Comment: You're right, I am using `UpdatePanel`, but forgot to set a trigger for it. How would you code a trigger in this situation?

Comment: Simple ... you just call the `.Update()` method of your `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Thanks for the update, thats' exactly what I was looking for, however after making changes the UpdatePanel still isn't refreshing. I'll look into it in more detail tomorrow morning and will keep this question updated.

Comment: Not a problem. Try what I did, isolate it out and get it working, then add pieces back in to see what is interfering.

Comment: I've ran into some AJAX issues with this project and decided scrap my callback-to-iframe idea. However in normal circumstances this solution would work, so I will mark it as accepted answer.